# Accessing IIS site information in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis, silverlight-4.0

I need to get the site name and port number of the IIS sites in the Silverlight Application. How to get that?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get this info from `Application.Current.Host.Source`

```
 string server = Application.Current.Host.Source.Host;
 int port = Application.Current.Host.Source.Port;
```

Comment: Ya. Using this i can able to get only the current site information from which the application is running. To get other sites, what should i do?

Comment: @mhn: Perhaps you could describe a scenario you are trying to solve.  "to get other sites" doesn't make a great deal of sense on its own.

Comment: Basically i need to access the service from silverlight app. That service is located in the different IIS site on the machine. So to build the service URL, i need that site name and port number.